# ActionScript AirPlay server with Adobe Air

Tags: actionscript-3, air, rtsp, airplay

Is it feasible to use ActionScript 3 to create a cross-platform server running as an Adobe AIR application that can play audio through AirPlay-enabled devices?

I want to write an AIR application to run on PC, Mac and mobile devices that will allow the user to play locally stored music through AirPlay devices such as Apple TV.  I'm new to ActionScript so have been hunting around for AirPlay samples to help me on my way, but they seem thin on the ground.

I have found this [unofficial AirPlay Protocol spec](http://nto.github.com/AirPlay.html) but can't find any ActionScript samples to help with RTSP which is also new to me.  (I haven't done any socket programming.) Before I devote a lot of time to the project I'd like to confirm that it is possible.  I don't mind putting in the work to write it from the bottom up but the fact that nobody else seems to have done this already or even asked about it is slightly worrying.

Comment: Anyone out there with any more information on this? Anyone? Please? Hello?

Answer (score 1):

I created an application like this a few years back for college.  What I remember is that during that time it wasn't possible.  I had to create a hack to make it kinda work in the way your talking about.  If you want I can get you send you my flex project.  The code maybe of some help.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your response.  Do you remember what it was that required a hack?  I'm hoping that the latest libraries will give me everything I need, ideally without even using native extensions.

Comment: It's really been a long time.  I'll have to think about it for a while and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Tim, were you able to pass on any more information to Buzzwig about this? Could you post any samples on here, or links to download any demo projects that tried to achieve this?

Comment: I'll try to remember to put up on git-hub later tonight and come back with a link.  Don't have those samples here at my office.